# Viewflipper setOutAnimation not showing

Tags: android, viewflipper

I'm trying to set my `ViewFlipper` animations. The flipper works correctly, it's just that the outanimation is not showing, only the inanimation, which looks wierd. Instead of the screen sliding out it just disappears and the new view comes in. 
Here's the code in Java.

```
vf.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_left);

vf.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_right);

vf.showNext();
```

And here it is in XML

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<translate
    android:duration="1400"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

As I said the flipper is working but it would be nice if the screen would slide out to the side. I would be very greatful for help. I have been Googling for it but haven't seen anyone else with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Animation `fromYDelta="0%"` to `toYDelta="%0"` ?! :D

Comment: I assume Y is for vertical, it's supposed to go horizontal, the X-values. I tried changing the Y-values but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Editing `toYDelta="%100"` should fix your problem :)